# javascript onmouseover/onmouseout stay in previous content until hover / trigger the next one

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover, onmouseout

I am a beginner of javascript. For this project we can not use jQuery here. I like to have rectangular 4 cells at the bottom right function as thumbnails and they will trigger to show different images when hover respectively.

```
<div id="resistorContent">
            <section id="resistorDetail1" class="1stdetailContent"><img src="http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/pic1.jpg" alt=""></section>
            <section id="resistorDetail2" class="detailContent"><img src="http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/pic2.jpg" alt=""></section>
            <section id="resistorDetail3" class="detailContent"><img src="http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/pic3.jpg" alt=""></section>
            <section id="resistorDetail4" class="detailContent"><img src="http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/pic4.jpg" alt=""></section>

            <span class="closeButton"><a id="close" onclick="hideContent('resistorContent')">X</a></span>

            <ul>
                <li onmouseover="showDetailContent('resistorDetail1')" onmouseout="hideDetailContent('resistorDetail1')"></li>
                <li onmouseover="showDetailContent('resistorDetail2')" onmouseout="hideDetailContent('resistorDetail2')"></li>
                <li onmouseover="showDetailContent('resistorDetail3')" onmouseout="hideDetailContent('resistorDetail3')"></li>
                <li onmouseover="showDetailContent('resistorDetail4')" onmouseout="hideDetailContent('resistorDetail4')"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</section>


<script type="text/javascript">
        function showDetailContent(target) {
            document.getElementById(target).style.display = "block";
        }

        function hideDetailContent(target){
            document.getElementById(target).style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
```

I like to make some improvement because these cells are now rely on `onmouseout` that turn off the linked `<section>` so it can reload the next `<section>`. If I move the mouse away from cells it will show a blank page.

How do I write the javascript to make it stays at the current `<section>`  and only load the other `<section>` when hover on the other cells?

Thank you in advance

http://jsfiddle.net/63L72trx/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down what you want to do to a simple sentence:

"When I show another item, I want to hide other items that may or may not be shown."

So, let's remove the `onmouseout` that hides the elements and force a "reset" state that ensures all items are hidden whenever we show an item from our `onmouseover`.

```
<div id="resistorContent">
  <section id="resistorDetail1" class="1stdetailContent"><img src="http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/pic1.jpg" alt=""></section>
  <section id="resistorDetail2" class="detailContent"><img src="http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/pic2.jpg" alt=""></section>
  <section id="resistorDetail3" class="detailContent"><img src="http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/pic3.jpg" alt=""></section>
  <section id="resistorDetail4" class="detailContent"><img src="http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/pic4.jpg" alt=""></section>
  <span class="closeButton"><a id="close" onclick="hideContent('resistorContent')">X</a></span>
    <ul>
      <li onmouseover="showDetailContent('resistorDetail1')"></li>
      <li onmouseover="showDetailContent('resistorDetail2')"></li>
      <li onmouseover="showDetailContent('resistorDetail3')"></li>
      <li onmouseover="showDetailContent('resistorDetail4')"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var children = document.querySelectorAll('#resistorContent > section[id]');
  function showDetailContent(target) {
    // Simply loop over our children and ensure they are hidden:
    for (var i = 0, child; child = children[i]; i++) {
      child.style.display = 'none';
    }
    // Now, show our child we want to show
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
  }
</script>
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/63L72trx/12/

Comment: Thank you ! However, it is acting a bit silly. it works if I hover in sequence like pic1 - pic2 - pic3 -pic4 . But if I first hover pic4 then it gets stuck, no pic3,2,1. If hover over pic3 first,  no more pic2 and pic1. What is causing the problem?

Comment: @DylanDaicySiao Oops. I forgot to assign `i = 0`. It's fixed now.

Comment: the same problem still exists. I have it on JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/63L72trx/10/

Comment: @DylanDaicySiao Your fiddle is quite more complex than your question. Perhaps something else is going on. Here's a simple fiddle that proves the above works fine with your question: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/63L72trx/12/ I'll add that to the answer for you.

Comment: you are right. thank you for the solution. I will go look into my own cods :)